# Laravel 5.2 Queue Using Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

From a controller, I dispatched a job to send a welcome email using

```
$this->dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail($user));
```

In **SendWelcomeEmail** Job I'm doing

```
public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $mailer->send('emails.welcome', ['data' => 'data'], function ($m) {
        $m->from('noreply@gmail.com', 'Noreply');
        $m->to('xyz@live.com', 'xyz')->subject('Welcome');
    });
}
```

My **.env** file is configured to be

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*access*
MAIL_PASSWORD=*key*
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Checked:

- Database migrations - 'Jobs' tables
- Ran the queue listener before job dispatch trigger using `php artisan queue:listen`

Problem: The jobs are loaded on to the 'jobs' table in the database but are not processed. But this **works** completely fine when I update the queue drive.

`QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`

What am i missing here?

Comment: The reason the sync driver works is because jobs are immediately processed with that driver set, there really is no interaction with a "queue" since its all synchronous. Did anything get logged out as far as exceptions? Timeouts?

Comment: Did you run php artisan queue:work

Comment: Yes - This was the error that got logged. - 

local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'

Answer (score 0):

Does your job have the following traits on the class?

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
```

And implement:

```
ShouldQueue
```

Comment: Implements ShouldQueue - Yes
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels - Only